# VBA Paste Not Following If Statement

Tags: excel, copy-paste, autofill, vba

I am working on code to paste multiple sequential columns down X rows only if the value in column AH is greater than zero. However, it is pasting in every row instead of rows that are only greater than zero.

Here is what I have:

```
Sub Fill_Down_MSP_Info()

ActiveSheet.Range("E11:AD11").Select
Selection.Copy

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("AH11:AH153")
    If cell.Value > 0 Then
        Dim example As Range
        Set example = Range("AH11:AH153")
        example.Offset(0, -29).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You want to paste the value in the same row, or at the next empty slot in column X?

Comment: BTW I think that you could do this with a simple formula.

Comment: you're copying an entire range and pasting it in a specific cell, that is undoubtedly not what you intend to do. You should be able to do this with a formula, as @A.S.H mentions, or you can modify this code to avoid `Paste` method entirely. At the very least, you should not be copying the full range of data outside the loop, and subsequently pasting the full range of data in a single cell inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intent to keep the copy/paste as is, you can use a formula after the fact and delete rows which do not meet your criteria:

```
Dim i as Integer

For i = 153 to 11 Step -1 'Since your paste range is AH11:AH153
    If Cells(i,34).Value<=0 Then 'AH is 34th column
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

If you want to be more dynamic, you can do something similar to this:

```
Dim LR as Long
Dim i as Integer

LR = Cells(Sheets("REF").Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = LR to 11 Step -1
    If Cells(i,34)<=0 Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

This reverse-step will start with the last row of the column and go backwards til the top, as to not cause an error when the last row keeps changing (defined before it starts the loop) after deleting rows.